# Problem with multiple cursors in VSCode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, cursors

How do I stop multiple cursors from appearing at the terminal's command line in VS Code?

[image: VS Code screenshot showing two cursors on one terminal command line]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, just go to terminal settings->window-> and turn off gpu accelaration.